Estoy documentando un proyecto en NodeJS con Swagger, mi problema surge al acabar de configurar el yaml no me permite testear las rutas en SwaggerUI
Aqui dejare el codigo de error arrojado por SwaggerUI, agradezco cualquier ayuda:
Resolver error at paths./api/user.get.responses.200.content.application/json.schema.items.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/User does not exist in document
